# Crash dump implies register value changed between sequential instructions

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, driver, crash-dumps

I'm currently analyzing a crash dump from a customer that resulted from a BSOD. I can't provide the crash dump for confidentiality reasons, but I've come to a bit of a dead end.

The crash occurs in the `RtlSetBit` function within the DDK. Here's the context record:

```
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=fffff8800282da00 rcx=fffffa8007c10340
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000001 rdi=fffffa8007c102e0
rip=fffff8000168d0b4 rsp=fffff880057478e8 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000 r10=fffff88001e5dca0
r11=0000000000000000 r12=0000000000000000 r13=fffffa800812feb0
r14=0000000000000001 r15=fffff88003490af0
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
nt!RtlSetBit+0x4:
fffff800`0168d0b4 0fab10          bts     dword ptr [rax],edx ds:002b:00000000`00000000=????????
```

Here's the assembly for `RtlSetBit`:

```
fffff800`0168d0b0 488b4108        mov     rax,qword ptr [rcx+8]
fffff800`0168d0b4 0fab10          bts     dword ptr [rax],edx << Exception
fffff800`0168d0b7 c3              ret
```

What's odd is that, as you can see, `rax` doesn't contain the contents of `rcx+8`:

```
2: kd> dq rcx+8
fffffa80`07c10348  fffffa80`07c10338 0000000b`00000014
```

Instead, `rax` shows null.

How is this possible? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

The value was probably 0 at the time the `mov rax, qword ptr [rcx+8]` executed. Before the `bts` could execute, another thread modified the value in memory. You then crash on the `bts`, and when you look at memory, you see the updated value, not the original 0.

Answer (score 0):

You assume, that the instruction before, the move is executed. But just because it is in the assembler before it, it does not necessarily mean that it is executed before. A jump straight to the bts could lead to such a misbehaviour.

Reason for this jump could either be wrong code (dont know if you have handwritten/optimized assembler), or a stack/buffer/array-overflow, that modified the return address on the stack, and made the bts the return address, and others more obscure bugs.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that the `mov` executes (or was attempted to be executed). The assembly I provided is the entirety of the RtlSetBit function. Nothing I can see would indicate an overflow of any sort.

Comment: @ReferentiallySeethru: That has nothing to do with the function RtlSetBit buggy. It could be the jump target by everything else in your whole program, completely unrelated to RtlSetBit, it is just a random jump target. If you dont have a debugger and are able to reproduce it, such errors are REALLY hard to debug. A hint could you maybe get, by looking at stack and check if the call stack looks sane, i.e. check if the function before on the call stack is really able to call your RtlSetBit. But this cannot disprove a "misjump", only prove if you got one.

Comment: Yes, the call stack looks sane which is why I didn't believe a 'misjump' was the culprit. I'm not dismissing what you're saying is possible, just that it seems very unlikely in the current situation. I'll keep this in mind, though, if we're unable to progress further.